# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, logcat

In MainActivity class , I have the following code to go to settings.class .

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Settings.class);
startActivity(intent1);
```

But I have got exception . THe logcat shows the following error .

```
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.commlink.messaging/com.commlink.messaging.Settings}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1634)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1430)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3507)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3459)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3710)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3678)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at com.commlink.messaging.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:105)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2674)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1074)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:206)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1152)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3014)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3865)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
11-17 12:31:50.245: E/AndroidRuntime(11166):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have decalred Settings.class in menifest.xml . My menifest.xml file is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.commlink.messaging"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"  >
        <activity
            android:name="com.commlink.messaging.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>    
             <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" /> 
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
             </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                 android:name="android.app.searchable"
                 android:resource="@xml/searchable" />        
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.commlink.messaging.New_Message"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.commlink.messaging.Settings"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>


          <receiver android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" /> 
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".MmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Activity that allows the user to send new SMS/MMS messages -->
        <activity android:name=".ComposeSmsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />                
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
        <service android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
                 android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
                 android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

What can I do to solve this exception ?

Comment: remove  `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>`  from `Settings Activity`

Comment: I have removed . But the same exception I have got

Comment: `Clean and built` your project and try again..

Comment: I have used Eclipse .

Comment: You should really switch to Studio. Eclipse has these nagging issues. You could try removing your "build" folder, restarting Eclipse and doing clean and build. Normally this would solve the issue.

Comment: `<activity android:name=".Settings" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>`

Comment: Use Android Studio for better approach

Comment: https://argillander.wordpress.com/2011/11/25/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-class/

Comment: check if it is exists in same package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `AndroidManifest.xml` like this.
change your android:name like this. because your package name already in build in top of the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
   <activity
        android:name=".Settings"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>
```

Comment: I have done this . But I have got the same exception .

Comment: Does your answer make any difference?

Comment: show your app hierarchy. because according to your error you have add to same package name

Comment: I think the issue is not in the code. It is a legendary problem with Eclipse. So happy that Google ditched it for AS.